# Agrupar três comandos em um só

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Meu dataframe se chama f0219. O seguinte comando filtra uma coluna desse df chamada Tiporubrica quando o código é igual a 2; esse filtro é atribuído à variável f0219Teto;
Em seguida, outro comando agrupa o novo dataframe criado, f0219Teto, pela Matricula e Nome, e soma o conteúdo da coluna "Valor", atribuindo o resultado à variável f0219somaTeto.
Por fim, Verifica se algum salário ultrapassou o teto estabelecido. São três comandos para fazer isso. Eles estão funcionando, e retornam exatamente o que eu quero. Porém, eu gostaria de agrupar esses três comandos em um só. COmo posso fazer isso?

```
f0219Teto = f0219[f0219.Tiporubrica == 2] # filtra por codigo igual a 2

f0219somaTeto = f0219Teto.groupby(['Matricula', 'Nome'])['Nome','Valor'].sum() # agrupa por matricula e soma

f0219somaTeto[f0219somaTeto.Valor>39200] # verifica se houve ganho acima do teto
```

Dataframe exemplo que estou trabalhando: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlG8j.png

Comment: Poderia colocar uma pequena amostra dos dados para entender a estrutura? Não precisa ser extamente os mesmo, mas de modo que possa manipulá-los.

Comment: Alterei a pergunta original com o dataframe exemplo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode reduzir os 3 comandos em uma única linha unindo a **primeira e terceira** condições dentro de um (1)`loc` usando (2)`groupby` com (3)`transform`, assim:

```
f0219.loc[(f0219.Tiporubrica == 2) & (f0219.groupby(['Matricula', 'Nome']) \
['Valor'].transform('sum') > 39200)].groupby(['Matricula', 'Nome']) \
['Valor'].sum().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

Roger, entendo que é impossível você agrupar os três comandos da forma que você quer. Isso porque a partir do momento que você utiliza **groupby**, ele retorna um DataFrame (DF) novo com outra constituição, impossibilitando você filtrar (>39200) sem alocar esse DF em uma nova variável. O que você poderia fazer é agrupar os 2 primeiros comandos, atribuir a uma variável como f0219_grouped e depois realizar o filtro. Exemplo abaixo:

#### Definindo o DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Matricula': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3], 
        'Nome': ['jose', 'jose', 'jose', 'jose', 'maria', 'pedro'], 
        'Tiporubrica': [2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3],
        'Valor': [4749.33, 8411.01, 1472.29, 6208.33, 444.22, 1258.41]}

f0219 = pd.DataFrame(data)
f0219

#Saída
    Matricula   Nome    Tiporubrica     Valor
0           1   jose              2     4749.33
1           1   jose              2     8411.01
2           1   jose              2     1472.29
3           1   jose              2     6208.33
4           2   maria             1     444.22
5           3   pedro             3     1258.41
```

#### Criando o DF agrupado

```
f0219_grouped = f0219[f0219.Tiporubrica >= 2].groupby(['Matricula', 'Nome'])['Nome','Valor'].sum()
f0219_grouped

#Saída  
Matricula   Nome    Valor   
1           jose    20840.96
3           pedro   1258.41
```

#### Aplicar o Fitro

```
f0219_grouped[f0219_grouped.Valor > 2000]

#Saída      
Matricula   Nome    Valor   
1           jose    20840.96
```

Com isso, você reduz 3 comandos para 2, mas não há forma de reduzir para apenas 1 utilizando o pandas **group_by**.

Comment: Olá, você exemplificou o primeiro comando populando dados novos. Tem como exemplificar com o dataframe já existente, que eu postei na imagem? Grato.